# How to create a directory structure using maven pom xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I have a maven based project containing a pom.xml file. When I hit the command:

mvn clean install or whatever

I'd like it to create a directory structure such as

`project_root/dir1/temp
project_root/dir2/engine
project_root/dir2/content
project_root/dir2/new
project_root/dir2/old`

This is in addtion to the `target`, `src`, etc...

I'm not interested in `mkdir -p <path to create>`

I'd like to have this directory creating logic inside the pom xml file.

Any way to do this? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `maven archetype` might help you to create templates as you want and use it

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write a new arche-type for your requirements as it seems to be not a very generic model . You can take an archetype that suits you better , download the actual source and add your directories in the artifactDescriptor and repackage it ( quick fix ).

EDIT
https://github.com/sundarmr/mavenarchetypes/tree/master/myarchetype , as desired , but i would not recommend creating such projects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [How To Create Web Project Directory Structure in Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)

OR  [Maven Directory Structure](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-using-maven-in-eclipse/)